# how to dockerize my nodejs express application hosted on amazon linux ami?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, docker, redis

1.my technology stack for above application is expressjs, nodejs, mongoDB, redisDB, s3(storage).
2.API is hosted on Linux AMI
3.I need to create docker container image for my application.

Comment: What have you done till now and what are the problems you are facing?

Comment: try ECS(elastic container service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to decide to either keep everything inside a single container (monolithic, cannot really recommend it) or separate the concern and run a separate express/nodejs container, a mongodb container, and a redisDB container, s3 is a service you cannot run for yourself,

If you chose the later approach, there are already officially supported images on the docker hub for redis, and mongo, now for the actual app server (node) you need to set express  as a dependency on node and start the official node image with an npm install command (which would get express on it) and then npm start (or whatever command you use for it), dont forget to include your code as a volume for this to work,

Now, bear in mind that if your app uses any reference data inside mongodb, you should make sure to insert it when the mongodb container starts or create an image based on the official mongodb that already has said data on it!

Another valuable note is that you should pass all connections inside your expressjs app as env vars, that way you can change them when deploying your app container (useful for when you distribute your system accross several hosts),

At the end of the day you would then start the containers in this order: mongodb, redis, and node/express. Now, the connection to s3 should already be handled inside your node app, so it is irrelevant in this context, just make sure the node app can reach the bucket!

If you want just to build a monolithic container, just start with a debian jessie image, get a shell inside the container, install everything as you would on a server, get your code running and commit the image to your repo, then use it to run your app, Still i cannot recommend this approach at all!

BR,

Comment: bear in mind that there are several ways to approach this problem, this is just 2 of them!

Comment: I'm working on Windows and dockerize my nodejs application using docker compose. Can I run the same on Linux AMI or I need to create separate images on ec2 and then proceed for applications run command.?

Comment: on windows the docker daemon runs on top of a virtualized linux subsystem, so 99% of the stuff would work on either one, apart from paths! you may need to debug a little bit when changin os, but again, most should be fine.